# ¿Cómo hacer update desde java?

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, update

Estoy haciendo un código simple en java vinculado a mysql.

Los datos ingresados en el código deben de ser por el usuario. Ya hice el código para el registro, el *insert*, pero no se como se implementa el *update* teniendo en cuenta que el usuario escoja que cambio modificar.

Estaba haciendo algo asi

```
public void Update(String Nom) {
    //stmt.executeUpdate("update plan set Nombre='sara' where Nombre='s7ara'");
    try {           
        stmt =CON.createStatement();
        
        if(Nom==?????)
        {
            
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo actualizar dato..." + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En caso de que estes utilizando JDBC, en vez de utilizar createStatement, deberías de utilizar prepareStatement.
Tu código debería de ser algo parecido a esto:

```
public void Update(String Nom) {
try {           
    stmt =CON.prepareStatement("update plan set Nombre='sara' where  Nombre='s7ara'");
   stmt.executeUpdate();
    
    if(Nom==?????)
    {
        
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("No se pudo actualizar dato..." + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Un saludo,

me quedo a la espera de tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Usa [Consultas Preparadas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) para evitar la inyección SQL, y cuando realices alguna modificación a la base datos tipo (insert, update) usa [autocommit, Commit, and Rollback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html) para manejar los estados de actualización ejecutados por sistema de gestión de base de datos relacional (RDBMS).
Ejemplo:

```
public void Update() {
   
    String consultaSQL="update A set B=? where  C=?";
    try{
            cn=DBConn.getConnection();//creamos una conexión a la base de datos
            cn.setAutoCommit(false); 
            pst=cn.prepareStatement(consultaSQL);
            pst.setString(1, valorB);
            pst.setString(2, valorC);            
            pst.executeUpdate();
            cn.commit();
            cn.close();           
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {           
            cn.rollback();
            System.out.println("Se activó el Rollback"); 
            System.out.println("error " + ex);            
    }
}
```

**Donde:**
A: nombre de la tabla de la base de datos donde se va actualizar

B: nombre de la columna de la tabla de la base de datos donde se va actualizar

C: nombre de la columna de la base de datos donde una o varias filas van a cumplir una condición.

valorB: el valor que vas actualizar en la base de datos

valorC: el valor de la condición, normalmente es el id

**Cambiando los valores por un ejemplo real quedaría**

```
String consultaSQL="update Factura set nombre=? where  id=?";
pst.setString(1, "teclados gamer");
pst.setString(2, "00100");
```

Comment: Comprendo, solo que mi duda mas especifica es la siguiente tabla empleado: id 4558, nombre jose, telefono 55454545, para aplicar la actualizacion se genera UPDATE empleado SET nombre=?, telefon=? where id=?, pero como le harias si el usuario solo quiere modiciar el telefono y no el nombre????

Comment: @PatasDeRobot se puede actualizar uno p más campos de la tabla, en el ejemplo que te muestro está dado para actualizar sólo el nombre.